# Microsoft DOCX, XLSX and PPTX Archive

Tags: c#, docx, xlsx

I'm building an application that needs to programmatically extract all embedded files, images and text from DOCX, XLSX and PPTX files.  As I look into DOCX files, I see that they are just zip packages.  In the root of the package there is always a file called [Content_Types].xml.  Inside this file I can find the location of the Document.xml file that contains all the text.  This is necessary because, from what I understand, the file is not always guaranteed to be in the same place.  This is easy enough, but I can't find any docs specifying how all the images and embedded files (word or Ole Containers) are stored.

It looks to me like all embedded files are added to the Embeddings directory and all the images are added to the Media directory.  However, I can't find anything that tells me that for sure. Also, none of the xml files within the archive show any location information for stored images and files, so I am left to think they are *always* in Embeddings and Media directories.

Like I mentioned, I need to extract all embedded files, images and text from DOCX, XLSX and PPTX files.  I need to do this on the server where I will not have Office installed.  If anyone has already done this and could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Thanks,

Comment: did you pick up the specs at http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/index.html You are interested in ISO/IEC 29500-1:2011
It describes how the xml and the zip works

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I just started gonig through the document - WOW, almost 6000 pages of pure joy.  I hope to skip to the good parts :-)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have an SDK for processing XML office documents called "Open XML SDK", which is supported also on Servers.

I have not tried myself, but it presumably contains APIs to extract elements such as embedded objects without dealing with the zip files or the ISO documentation yourself. That would also be safer, as the file structures might change over time.

Kemal